# How do you write a query in JPA repository in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to pull a single string from my sql table using a query in my JPA repository. I have a repository, service, and controller class. My repository query looks like

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT title FROM table_name WHERE subject = term;", nativeQuery = true)
String getTitleBySubject(String term);
```

My service method looks like this

```java
public String getTitleBySubject(String term) {
    String title = (String) repo.getTitleBySubject(term);
    return title;
}
```

My controller call is

```
service.getTitleBySubject("subject");
```

Why does this return `null`? This is printed to the console

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT title FROM table_name WHERE subject = term;", nativeQuery = true)
String getTitleBySubject(String term);
```

to

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT title FROM table_name WHERE subject = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
String getTitleBySubject(String term);
```

Reference document: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: It's always the little things... Thank you so much!